# My service doesn't get my Post entity (PostAsJsonAsync)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Hi i'm new on programming and i'm working on some code. When i want to post a created entity my service return a null entity and go on error 400 BadRequest and i can't understand why

```
var action = _url + "/NewUser";
EntityUser newUser = new EntityUser();
try
{
   newUser.Id = 1;
   newUser.Name = "Jack";
   newUser.Surname = "Black";

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<EntityUser>(action, newUser);
}
```

this is the other part of the code on my service where my User is null

```
public async Task<long> NewUser(EntityUser user)
{
return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new DtoUser().NewUser(user));
}
```

I'm sure my user isn't null when i post it so i don't understand why he doens't get it. It should create another user from the data i gave him.

Comment: Main issude would be the parameter: `NewUser([FromBody] EntityUser user)`

Comment: Side note: get rid of the StartNew() stuff. When DtoUser does not have async methods, just return via `Task.FromResult()`

Comment: does your `EntityUser` class have a parameterized constructor?